# Sum of aggregates in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I'm trying to get the total of all the rows of a column(Sum of aggregates) . I used a custom code for that.

```
Public Shared Dim Total as Decimal
Public Shared Function Initialize()
Total=0
End Function

Public Function GetValue(ByVal value as Decimal) as Decimal
Total=Total+value
return Total
End Function
```

I have used 'Shared' because,in the new page the total value is initializing to 0 again. But, when using 'Shared', the total value gets increased every time when I navigate to a certain page.

I'm using the below expressions in the cells.

```
=Code.GetValue(Expression)     --Group rows
=Code.Total                    --Row within the group
=Code.Total                    --Last row after all the groups
```

Note: I'm returning total from the function, only to find the issue( Total initializing to 0 in new page and when 'Shared' is used to tackle that, the values are getting incremented during every visit to the page.

I need the total value to be 0 after each group and display the grand total value at last row.

Can someone please help with this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just having one doubt, you want to say that you want per page wise total at the end of every page and finally all page wise total at end of report?

Comment: I want row group wise total and sum of all row group wise total at the end

Comment: can you please upload any image for reference with example?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I obtained the desired solution by directly modifying the stored procedure result structure